# D3 map - How do I include SVG image files in JSON data to create custom location markers?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to figure out how to include svg icon images in with my json data so the relevant icon will appear as a marker at the corresponding coordinates.

I've got the data in files separated by what shape of object was sighted (I'm mapping ufo sightings through the 20th century), and I created an svg image file for each shape as well.

I'm not sure what the best way is to connect the images to the data though. (I'm a relative beginner). here's a visual to help explain what I mean:

```json
{   "date": "10/21/1989",   "shape": "Triangle",   "latitude": -41.05446,   "longitude": -130.72728,   "color": "violet" },
```

then I've got a corresponding 'Triangle.svg' icon in an 'icons' folder. I'm sure the solution is not a complicated one, I'm just not seeing it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

It will be easier for you to switch from JSON to JS and use the following structure:

```
import TRIANGLE from '../path/to/triangle.svg';

const data = {
  date: '10/21/1989',
  shape: TRIANGLE,
  latitude: -41.05446,
  longitude: -130.72728,
  color: 'violet',
}
```

In case you are receiving the data from an API, try to get the full name and the path to the public folder. So you can have your images referenced as:

```
<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/triangle.svg'} /> // here change triangle for your shape, in a loop or the way you render them.
```

More info on the PUBLIC_URL: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Comment: Thanks Kevin! I like the first solution; but I'm going to need to create a variable for each shape as they all appear in more than one location. how would you go about that?

Comment: Hi @GideonSCrawley There are not many options to go about that, you'll have to declare the variables where they are used. If you have many DATA constants, you can declare them all in one file and export from the same source, so you avoid importing each shape multiple times.

Comment: ok so I've made an icons.js file with objects containing the svg code for a couple of the icon markers and exported those into a new sightings.js and put the json code for those two objects in there. but how do I now incorporate this js file into my map component? here's the code for the map: